# Remove Column using GridView to Export to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am binding a gridView to a `List<model>`. I am able to export it to an excel file but I am not able to remove a specific column. Any Ideas on how do so? I tried `gridView.Columns.RemoveAt(myIndex)` but didn't work and threw a null exception and I am assuming this is because the gridView is not binded to a dataTable.

```
var models = new ModelService().List(startDate, DateTime.Now);
var gridView = new GridView { DataSource = models };                       

gridView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert to a dataset or data table

```
foreach (GridViewRow dr in gridView.Rows)
{
  //Create dataset and insert into cell value.
  dr.Cells[0].Text;
  dr.Cells[1].Text;
}
```

remove the desired rows

```
for (int j = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
{
  if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[j][column].ToString() == criteria)
  {
    ds.Tables[0].Rows.RemoveAt(j);
  }
}
```

then export the dataset

Comment: Thanks it worked although I wish there is a better way than doing a data transfer object.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1. Use LINQ to select just the columns you want from your ModelService so that the columns you don't want never make it to the grid.
2. Define your columns in the GridView and hide the ones you don't want when exporting to Excel. I do this anyway becuase I want more control over the formatting of the columns.

Comment: The model object is pretty much static. Model object might have address attribute that I don't want it to show in gridView. How would I define the columns in gridView?